# Angular 7 add price, quantity and vat of services dynamically added to form array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form array using form builder and each array contains a service. I want to add the price, amount, and vat for each service and display that in the total column. I know that I have to listen to the input changes using valueChange method but I am not sure how to get the index for each service and apply the value to the total column. This code is currently what I have any help would be much appreciated

```js
  addValues() {
    var services = this.invoiceForm.get('service');
    services.valueChanges.subscribe(
      val => {
        console.log(val)
      }
    );
  }
```

So far when I edit a field it prints the service form array but how can I get the individual service fields and add them together each time there is a change?

Comment: You gonna have to add a lot more code. What does this.invoiceForm.get('service'); return? is it the formArray? Where is addValues() called from, when is called?

Comment: It returns a form Array and the addValue is called in init function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it I'm  not sure if this is the best way to do it but will update answer if I come up with a better solution

```js
    calculateTotal() {
var services = this.invoiceForm.get('service');
services.valueChanges.subscribe(
  (val) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      var price = services.value[i].price;
      var quantity = services.value[i].quantity;
      var vat = services.value[i].vat;
      services.value[i].total += (price * quantity) + ((vat / 100) * (price * quantity))
      console.log(services.value[i].total);
    }
  }
)
  }
```